# leetcode: Getting stuck in while-loop

Tags: python

I'm doing question 30, leetcode: 'Substring with Concatenation of All Words'

I'm  getting right answer in pycharm but "memory time is exceeding" while submission of the code.
I think its getting stuck in `while` loop.

It's accepting when I run these variables:

```
s="barfoothefoobarman"
words=["foo","bar"]
```

or

```
s="wordgoodgoodgoodbestword"
words=["word","good","best","word"]
```

or

```
s="barfoofoobarthefoobarman"
words=["bar","foo","the"]
```

but when I submit it's getting time limit exceeded with series of just "aaaaaa....."
["time limit exceeded" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrjtE.jpg)

The code:

```
class Solution:

    def findSubstring(self, s: str, words: List[str]) -> List[int]:
        result = []
        lenw = len(words[0])
        len2 = len(words)
        w2w2 = len2 * lenw
        list1 =collections.Counter(words)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i:i+len(words[0])] in list1:
                rr=Counter()
                for word in words:
                    rr[word]+=1
                ss=s[i:w2w2+i]
                count=0
                for zz in range(len(ss)):
                    while ss[zz:len(words[0])+zz] in rr:
                        rr[ss[zz:len(words[0])+zz]]-=1
                        count+=1
                        if rr[ss[zz:len(words[0])+zz]] == 0:
                            del rr[ss[zz:len(words[0])+zz]]
                        if count==len2:
                            result.append(i)
                        else:
                            zz=zz+len(words[0])
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                i +=1

        return result
```

Comment: Omg... please describe all the variable names...

Comment: i dont even know what variable leetcode is using while giving this particular error,could you please see the image

Comment: I think you missed the hint of the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process through the string, looking for an eligible word, then check if it is followed by all the others when you find one.  Using a Counter (from collections) for the words will make this go faster because it allows you to quickly check for an eligible word, and you can use a Counter comparison to check that the sequence of words cover the whole set of required words.

```
from collections import Counter
def findConcat(s,words):
    wordset = Counter(words) # words in a multiset for performance
    size    = len(words[0])  # size of each word
    span   = size*len(words) # size of the concatenation of words
    result = []
    for i in range(len(s)):  # advance throug fixed sized words
        w = s[i:i+size]
        if w not in wordset: continue          # detect eligible word
        wordSpan = Counter(s[j:j+size] for j in range(i,i+span,size))
        if wordset==wordSpan:                  # check word sequence
            result.append(i)                   # all words followed
    return result


print(findConcat("barfoothefoobarman",["foo","bar"])) # [0,9]
print(findConcat("barfoofoobarthefoobarman",["bar","foo","the"])) # [6, 9, 12]
```

*Note I am using a `Counter` instead of a `set` because the words can repeat and a set would not take that into account*